# Vaadin 10/Flow theming with Lumo

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin10

I'm having some trouble understanding Vaadin 10 theming: I've read all documentation on site but I can't solve my problem.

For example: if I start a plain Vaadin 8 application from scratch, when I stop the server I get a nice notification from disconnection:

[image]

But with a new Vaadin 10 starter (project base), i get this ugly notification
[image]

Both application are standard without any edit from Vaadin starters.
I've tried playing with *shared-styles.html* but without success.

**My questions, all vaadin 10 related:**

1. Is Lumo theme with this look by default, or it looks this way because I'm missing some imports or settings?
2. How can I apply the "dark" style for Lumo theme (i mean the whole application)?
3. How and where can I apply a global style variable, like for example a different primary color or a background color?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It's the default look.
2. Mark your router components with `@Theme(value = Lumo.class, variant = Lumo.DARK)`.
3. You can use Lumo's CSS custom properties in a CSS rule in the styles file. For example: `html{--lumo-base-color: aliceblue;}`.

Example use of the [`@Theme`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/11.0.2/com/vaadin/flow/theme/Theme.html) annotation on the usual `MainView` class:

```
@Route ( "" )
@Theme ( value = Lumo.class, variant = Lumo.DARK )  // ⬅ Add annotation 
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout { … }
```

And here's how you can customize the disconnection notification:

```
<custom-style>
  <style>
    html {
      --lumo-base-color: aliceblue;
    }

    .v-reconnect-dialog {
      visibility: visible;
      border: 1px solid lightslategray;
      background-color: slategray;
      color: lightgray;
      box-shadow: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
      border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .custom {
      color: lightskyblue;
    }
  </style>
</custom-style>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks so much! In this case I don't have to import anything into _shared-style.html_ because I'm using Lumo, and it's all packed into Vaadin, right?

Comment: Right. No need to import anything from the `shared-style.tml` file.

Comment: FYI, apparently another option is setting any component/layout by code: `someWidget.getElement().setAttribute( "theme" , "dark" );`

Comment: please provide examples where to save the custom styles file and how to import it.